# Aligning 3 text nodes in 2 rows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-positioning

I want to make the following:

[image]

- Blue node and red node are touching each other, with their text on the same baseline
- The green node is positioned 1pt below them, and its right edge is aligned with the red node.

What I have at the moment is not satisfactory. If I change a font face or font size the green one moves unwantedly and baseline of text 1 and 2 is not the same.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (t1) [fill=red]
  {text 1,};
\node [left=0pt of t1,fill=blue,text=white,draw=orange] (t2)
  {slightly longer text};
\node [below left=0.5pt and -1.1cm of t1,fill=green,text=white,text width=.5\textwidth,align=left] (t3)
  {a much longer text with some line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I guess I need to use some `anchor`s and `base` keys but I need some help with it.

Comment: I guess you want to be able to change fonts for each box individually?

Comment: Thats Correct. Each one is supposed to be in a different language

Comment: In that case I would think that your best bet will be to search the TikZ manual to see if there is a baseline anchor (no idea, but there might be) and if there is none, set the additional spacing of your box around your text to a fixed value and then do the alignment calculation yourself by measuring your text's size by putting it in a box first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the problem to solve so, like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (t1) [fill=red, outer sep=0pt]
  {text 1,};
\node [left=0pt of t1.base west, anchor=base east, fill=blue, text=white, draw=orange] (t2) {slightly longer text};
\node [below left = 1pt and 0pt of t1.south east, fill=green, text=white, text width=.5\textwidth, align=left, outer sep=0pt] (t3)
  {a much longer text with some line breaks};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. Like that. Well done!